# when the shared pointers gets destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am reading the following piece of code as explained by the comments.

```
#include <memory>

struct myClass {
    ~myClass() {
        cout << "dtor" << endl;
    }
};

void myFunc() {
    shared_ptr<myClass> sp2;
    {
        shared_ptr<myClass> sp( new myClass);
        myClass& obj = *sp;
        sp2 = sp; // OK, resource shared
        myClass& obj2 = *sp; // OK, both pointers point to same resource
        // sp destroyed here, yet no freeing: sp2 still alive
    }
    cout << "out of inner block" << endl;
    // sp2 destroyed here, reference count goes to 0, memory is freed
}
```

My question is, how come both pointers point to same resource for `myClass& obj2 = *sp;`?  And why is `sp` destroyed at point where we reach the comment `// sp2 destroyed here, reference count goes to 0, memory is freed`?

Comment: _"And why `sp` is destroyed at the the place where as commented?"_ Because it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that how come both pointers point to same resource for `myClass& obj2 = *sp;`?

That does not make sense. They probably meant:

```
myClass& obj2 = *sp2; // OK, both pointers point to same resource
                 ^^^ sp2, not sp
```

> And why `sp` is destroyed at the the place where as commented?

That's because `sp` is constructed in a nested scope introduced by

```
shared_ptr<myClass> sp2;
{  // This starts a new scope
  ....
} // This ends the scope
```

At the end of the nested scope, all automatic variables are destructed.

From the standard:

> **3.7.3 Automatic storage duration [basic.stc.auto]**
>
> 1 Block-scope variables explicitly declared `register` or not explicitly declared `static` or `extern` have automatic storage duration. The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits.

Comment: I thought `sp` gets destroyed after `}`, why before `}`?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: What do you mean by "before" or "after" the `}`? It's destroyed as the program leaves the block, the end of which is denoted by the `}`.

Comment: @Allanqunzi, the scope ends at the closing `}`. The standard says that automatic variables must be destructed at end end of the scope. The life of an object doesn't exist after the end of the scope. See 3.7.3/1 of the standard.

Comment: Why `*sp2` and not `*sp`?  They're equivalent.  The comment probably should say "both references"

Comment: @BenVoigt, since the OP's question has the phrase "how come both pointers point to same resource", I thought `*sp2` made more sense in that context.

Comment: @RSahu: Possibly it is a contrast with `std::auto_ptr`, showing that after `sp2 = sp;` both pointers are still valid (with `auto_ptr`, `*sp` would not be allowed at this point)

Comment: @BenVoigt, that's an interesting perspective. You are probably right.